# Directory Indexing - CPanel 500 server error

Tags: apache, indexing, cpanel, public-html

On CPANEL, I turned directory indexing from default to no indexing and its now showing 500 internal server error. Then I turned it back to default but I am still facing the same error. How can I correct this?

Comment: Please show a code-example and an error-log.

Comment: Check error log, and i am sure its not related to no indexing , it may be another .htaccess file error